# How do I use custom memory storage using aws amplify v6 and also persist the session on page refresh-Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I do not want to store my session details in localStorage, sessionStorage or cookies as they are vulnerable to xss attacks. I do know that aws amplify provides custom memory storage functionality but it does not persist the session on page refresh.

I tried using custom memory storage but the session is destroyed on refresh.